# react-day-picker DayPickerInput and setting selected date in another component

Tags: reactjs, state, react-day-picker

Using DayPicker in one component, I want to import the selected day into the TodoForm component, and use that value to set the state so that the selected day is saved and rendered in each todo.

```
class DayPickerComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleDayChange = this.handleDayChange.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            selectedDay: undefined,
            isEmpty: true,
            isDisabled: false
        }
    }

    handleDayChange(selectedDay, modifiers, dayPickerInput) {
        const input = dayPickerInput.getInput();
        this.setState({
            selectedDay,
            isEmpty: !input.value.trim(),
            isDisabled: modifiers.disabled === true
        })
    }

    render() {
        const today = new Date();
        const { selectedDay, isDisabled, isEmpty } = this.state;
        console.log('selectedDay: ', selectedDay)

        return (
            <span>
                <DayPickerInput
                    disabledDays={{
                        before: today
                    }}
                    onDayChange={this.handleDayChange}
                />
            </span>
        )
    }
}
```

The console.log(selectedDay); logs the selectedDay but how can I access the selectedDay value in the TodoForm component and set the state and render the selected day?

```
function TodoForm({addTodo}) {
  const initialState = {
    title: '',
    due_date: '',
    description: '',
    completed: false
  }

  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // if (state.title && state.due_date && state.description) {
      addTodo(state.title, state.due_date, state.description)
    // } else {
    //   alert('A task must contain a title, description, and a due date. Please add the required information and then submit.')
    // }
    resetInput();
  }

  function handleChange(e) {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setState({
      ...state,
      [e.target.name]: value,
    })
  }

  function resetInput () {
    setState(initialState);
  }

  return (
    <form id='form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <span className='title'>Title: </span>
        <input type='text' className='input' name='title' value={state.title} onChange={handleChange} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <span className='title'> Due Date: </span>
        {/* <input type='text' className='input' name='due_date' value={state.due_date} onChange={handleChange} /> */}
        <DayPickerComponent selectedDay />
      </div>
      <div>
        <span className='title'>Description: </span>
        <input type='text' className='input' name='description' value={state.description} onChange={handleChange} />

        <span id='add-button' className='add-button-wrapper'>
          <button id='add-button-appearance'>
            +
          </button>
          <span className='add-button-tooltiptext'>add</span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}
```

I'm also having a hard time disabling the dates before today but the state thing is my biggest issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as props

https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Inside DayPickerComponent you pass the selectedDay to TodoForm:

`<Todoform selectedDay={this.state.selectedDay} />`

Then you need to declare the props on the function TodoForm:

```
function TodoForm(props) {
.....
....
.
console.log(props.selectedDay)
.
...
.....
}
```

and so, you can call the selected day inside TodoForm as:

`props.selectedDay`

Comment: Did this helped you?